# Make the popup modal window Scrollable in JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to make the popup window using JQuery as Scrollable. could you tell me please what did I miss in the following code

```
$("#dvEnglish").dialog({ modal: true, width: '1300px', draggable: true, autoOpen: false });
```

The HTML is:

```
<div title="Search English" id="dvEnglish">
        <uc1:EnglishPopUp ID="EnglishPopUp1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

The Question has been updated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/):

> If the content length exceeds the maximum height, a scrollbar will
>   automatically appear.

So simply pass in the maxHeight and make sure you have enough content to cause it to need the scroll bars.

```
$("#dvEnglish").dialog({ modal: true, maxHeight: 500px, width: '1300px', draggable: true, autoOpen: false });
```

By the way, always a good idea to check the documentation before coming to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not Working my friend, is there anything that should be added to the div style ?

Comment: Works for me. Why don't you update your quesiton to include the applicable HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Check if property `overflow` of your div with id `dvEnglish` is not `hidden`

It should be `auto`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaRE/167/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the **overflow** property of the popup content div having id **"EnglishPopUp1"** to **"auto"**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dvEnglish").dialog({ modal: true, width: '1300px',draggable: true,
autoOpen: false, resizable: false, height: '500',maxHeight: '480px'});
```

It will work like above, and also with overflow.

The all answers seems like true. Thanks for All